# VBA - How to work with merged cells / big zones properly?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, error-handling, merge

After finishing a big project I am trying to make the code proper. I've took a look at [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) and i'am now doing my best to apply conscientiously the rules. I'am done with naming, commenting, testing etc.

I'am now trying to refactor the code. I have multiple sheets, with multiple zone containing thousands of cells. 
I am doing similar things on each zone so I tried to use general function instead of some lines of codes adapted to each zone. I've encoutered 2 problems depending on how I work.

Here is a simple exemple:

Before witing things in cells I want to clear them.

First option:

```
I loop trough zone and clear them.
      for each Zone in Zones
            zone.clearcontents
            [work on zone]
            for each cell in cells
                [work on cells]
            next
       next
```

This used to work, but after a second launch I got the error "too many different cells formats", I didn't know how to handle that so I've tried to go that way:

```
for each Zone in Zones
        [work on zone]
        for each cell in cells
        cell.clearcontents
            [work on cells]
        next
next
```

But now I've an error with merged cells, "cannot change parts of merged cells".

I don't know how to optimize the code, keep it simple and handle those errors.
How would you manage to solve this problem ?

Comment: 1) Download xlGeeks [xlStyles tool](http://www.copernici.com/Pages/XLStylesTool.aspx) to fix the *too many formats*. 2) Don't use merged cells. Ever. VBA hates them.

Comment: What would be the solution without add-ins ? (strict internet policy in my company)
What to do if the manager who designe the workbooks love to use merged cells ?

Comment: 1) The too many formats is a rare beast these days beyond xl2003, this really shouldn't be a routine issue to fix. 2) Use [Centre across Selecction](http://thenewpaperclip.com/2008/04/15/center-across-selection-the-merge-and-center-alternative-in-excel-2007/) instead